# Validation without using Properties file and Resource Bundle

Tags: spring

I want configuration for show error messages on jsp using spring validator,but without using **properties file**  and **resource bundle**

> org.springframework.context.**NoSuchMessageException**: No message found under code 'please enter user firstname.keyUserRegistration.firstName' for locale 'en_IN'

Is there **any other better mechanism** than resource bundle and properties file to localize the application?

Answer (score 0):

Try this method:

```
ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(errors, "your attribute","error.your attribute", "Error message")
```